# How to make a live preview of input element's in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html-formhandler

I want to make a live preview of input elements in HTML with the JavaScript. Like when use will write something in the field, it will automatically print the text under the field. So how can I make it? I have tried to make it in different ways. But every time I got undefined.

```js
const showCase = document.querySelector('#Message')
const field = document.querySelector('#Field')

field.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  field.addEventListener('keypress', () => {
    showCase.innerHTML = this.value
  })
})
```

Comment: Don't use an arrow function (which use the surrounding context's `this`), and stick with a single event listener, rather than nesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below.

`const myInput = document.getElementById('input'); // Input Element with id="input"
    const myOutput = document.getElementById('output'); // An empty paragraph with id="output"
function handleInputKeypress(e) {
  myOutput.textContent = e.target.value;
}

myInput.addEventListener('keyup', handleInputKeypress);`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const showCase = document.querySelector('#Message')
const field = document.querySelector('#Field')

// Listen for input event
field.addEventListener('input', e => {
    showCase.innerText = e.target.value
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)) for answering. I really apreciate that.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help :).
Also, heads up! If you can, use `.innerText` instead of `.innerHTML` as the latter can be a big security concern because it allows people to write actual HTML tags (including the `<script>` tag)

Comment: oh got it thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
const showCase = document.querySelector('#Message')
const field = document.querySelector('#Field')

field.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
 showCase.innerHTML=e.target.value
})
```

```html
<p id="Message"></p>
<input id="Field" type="text"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much mann!! It really works thanks a lot. :)))